# how I could get wikipages articles list in spanish?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

I have some code for get pages in english
I dont know how get this in spanish
In trying to change link to es
But not appear **ei continue**
What could I do

[lynx -dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=embeddedin&&eilimit=1000000&eititle=Template:Infobox&callback=?&eicontinue=0%7C12665)>wikinames

I have some code for get pages in English
Idon't know how get this in Spanish
in trying to change link to es
but not appear ei limit
what could I do

this is my English code

[lynx -dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=embeddedin&&eilimit=1000000&eititle=Template:Infobox&callback=?&eicontinue=0%7C12665)>wikinames

This is my final code

[lynx -dump](https://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=embeddedin&&eilimit=1000000&eititle=Template:Infobox&callback=?&eicontinue=0%7C12665)>wikinames

Please help me

Comment: changing subdomain from `en` to `es` works for me - EDIT:  ei limit should be 500 instead of 1000000 - take a look at the warning in the response

Comment: i change but no see the  eicontinue ?

Comment: Please take a look at their docs